# Exception Value: [Errno 32] Broken pipe - какие причины ошибки

Tags: html, django

Имеется рабочий сайт, но с недавнего времени выводится на определенную страницу эта ошибка `Exception Value: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`.

Страница запускается через локальный сервер с моего компа.

Действия, которые предшествовали ошибке: в гите перешел на ветку мастера, которая до этого не менялась и работала; серфил по интернету до степени подтормаживания компа (мало оперативы).

1. Какие причины этой ошибки?
2. Может ли эта ошибка быть по причине слабого компа?

Comment: С недавнего времени - это после добавления нового кода? Или смены железа (сервера)? Или провайдера/тарифа? Или ошибка проявляется только на определённом клиентском компьютере? Дополните пожалуйста вопрос.

Comment: Что у вас подключено через pipe? База данных или самописное подключение/синхронизация? Вы можете показать строку с ошибкой?

Comment: @Mae дополнил вопрос

Comment: @nick_n_a я не настолько компетентен, что бы ответить на пару первых вопросов. А стоку с ошибкой указал в вопросе (стока с ошибкой из страницы при загрузке).

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что через `./mange.py runserver`?

Comment: @НикитаКонин да, через `./mange.py runserver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина ошибки в том, что `runserver` не предназначен для реального использования. Broken pip возникает, например, если, запрос со стороны браузера был внезапно прерван.

Решение проблемы: использовать вместо `runserver` что-нибудь предназначенное не для разработки, а для реального использования. Например [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/).

Comment: А почему запросы со стороны браузера внезапно прерываются на постоянной основе? Т.е. всегда прерывается.

Comment: Как вариант из-за Java Script кода на странице, который выполняет запросы. 

Возможно причина вообще не в прерванных запросах, а в чем-то ещё. Но в любом случае `runserver` не предназначен для стабильной корректной работы.